# Use NGINX to map "directories" to applications

Tags: nginx

I'm not sure if my terminology is correct, so let me explain ...

If I have a domain, `test.example.com`, I want to be able to map `/abc` to an application on that server running on port `8080` and map another application `/def` to an application running on port `8081`.

I've tried it with RabbitMQ which I'm running inside docker and exposing port `15672`, NGINX however is not inside Docker and running directly on the machine.

```
docker run -d --hostname rabbitmq --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Whether it's running inside Docker or directly on the machine, I believe is irrelevant, I have an application running on port `15672` that I want to map to location `/rabbitmq`

My NGINX config I've tried so far:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.example.com;

        location /rabbitmq {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:15672;
        }
}
```

When going to `test.example.com/rabbitmq` I'm seeing the following:

[image]

I don't know if that's NGINX's page or RabbitMQ's page showing not found.

Opening port `15672` on the server I can clearly get to RabbitMQ

[image]

And going to `:15672/blah` it seems to be the same not-found page, so it must be getting to RabbitMQ.

[image]

RabbitMQ is listening on `0.0.0.0:15672`, so it should work from any domain, host or ip.

[image]

So how do I make `test.example.com/rabbitmq` actually serve the content of `test.example.com:15672` ?

Comment: I think port `15672` is not listening on `127.0.0.1` rather your local IP address. Also add logging and see what logs say.

Comment: I'm only seeing activity in the access logs from NGINX showing `/rabbitmq/` is being accessed. RabbitMQ's dashboard says it's listening on `0.0.0.0`, so all traffic on port `15672` should serve the dashboard page, whether it's localhost, 127.0.0.1 or a domain. Isn't there a way to rewrite the data while it's being proxied to the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working using a rewrite:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.example.com;

        location /rabbitmq {
                rewrite         /rabbitmq/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:15672;
                proxy_redirect  off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/1_www.danielecencig.com_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;
    server_name www.danielecencig.com; 
    root /www/public;

    rewrite  ^/$  /index.html  permanent;

    location / {
        root /www/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }

    location /SienaBikes {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_page 503 /error/maintenance.html;
        location ^~ /error/ {
        internal;
        root /www/public;
    } 
}
```

This is my nginx config; i'm using it aswell as a reverse proxy, but for my node app. "location /SienaBikes" is the nodejs app and it works properly for me.

One thing that I did (But I don't know if it applies for rabbitmq as well) is to install [PM2 Daemon](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) and run my node app as a process. Perhaps you need to do it as well or something along the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your NGINX config is fine just need to rewrite location mapping like below.

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name test.example.com;

        location /rabbitmq/ {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:15672;
        }
}
```